# error: ‘CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO’ undeclared when make m3u8-segmenter

Tags: c, ffmpeg, makefile, libavformat

I want to make m3u8-segmenter for Http Live Stream: https://github.com/johnf/m3u8-segmenter

There are errors when I make, the errors are:

```
gcc -g -O -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Waggregate-return -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wnested-externs -Wshadow -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Werror m3u8-segmenter.c -o m3u8-segmenter -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil
m3u8-segmenter.c: In function ‘add_output_stream’:
m3u8-segmenter.c:82:14: error: ‘CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO’ undeclared (first use in this function)
m3u8-segmenter.c:82:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
m3u8-segmenter.c:94:14: error: ‘CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO’ undeclared (first use in this function)
m3u8-segmenter.c: In function ‘main’:
m3u8-segmenter.c:338:5: error: ‘av_open_input_file’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:1090) [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
m3u8-segmenter.c:352:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘guess_format’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
m3u8-segmenter.c:352:5: error: nested extern declaration of ‘guess_format’ [-Werror=nested-externs]
m3u8-segmenter.c:352:10: error: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
m3u8-segmenter.c:371:18: error: ‘CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO’ undeclared (first use in this function)
m3u8-segmenter.c:376:18: error: ‘CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO’ undeclared (first use in this function)
m3u8-segmenter.c:387:5: error: ‘av_set_parameters’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:1434) [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
m3u8-segmenter.c:392:5: error: ‘dump_format’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:1559) [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
m3u8-segmenter.c:406:5: error: ‘url_fopen’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avio.h:279) [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
m3u8-segmenter.c:411:5: error: ‘av_write_header’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:1492) [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
m3u8-segmenter.c:444:67: error: ‘PKT_FLAG_KEY’ undeclared (first use in this function)
m3u8-segmenter.c:455:13: error: ‘put_flush_packet’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avio.h:293) [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
m3u8-segmenter.c:456:13: error: ‘url_fclose’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avio.h:280) [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
m3u8-segmenter.c:476:13: error: ‘url_fopen’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avio.h:279) [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
m3u8-segmenter.c:482:13: error: ‘av_write_header’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:1492) [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
m3u8-segmenter.c:514:5: error: ‘url_fclose’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avio.h:280) [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting those errors because for some reason, this block in `libav_compat.h` took effect:

```
/* Support older versions of ffmpeg and libav */
#if LIBAVCODEC_VERSION_INT < AV_VERSION_INT(52, 64, 0)
  #define AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO
  #define AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO
  #define AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY PKT_FLAG_KEY
#endif
```

But whichever headers are supposed to define `CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO` and `CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO` don't.  From the comment there, it looks like you probably should update your other software (ffmpeg and/or libav) and then try again.

Comment: I assume is happening with the latest version of the ffmpeg? https://github.com/carsonmcdonald/HTTP-Live-Video-Stream-Segmenter-and-Distributor/issues?sort=created&direction=desc&state=open